How to plot the live position of a robot in gazebo using ros2
As a beginner, this is the issue that I faced and couldn't find a direct answer too. Even though there are thousands of result articles available to cover the solution, but as a beginner to ros2 and gazebo, I coudn't find the right keywords to search it. So here I have given the simplest solution to get the live positions using /odom and then plotting them on matplot.
So here was the situation for me, I have built a mobile robot using ros2 foxy. Now I want to get the live positions of the robot, and then want to plot it on the rqt plot. What's the best and the easiest way to get the live positions and locations and then plot them to get our specific results.

The best way to get the position of your moving robot in the gazebo is to include a gazebo plugin in your urdf file. In my case, I had separate files for robot design, gazebo control, and compiling.

So I included the plugin in the gazebo_control_xacro file
The name of the plugin is gazebo_ros_p3d. Here is the code of the plugin
<plugin name="gazebo_ros_p3d" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <ros>
        <!-- Use your desired namespace or leave empty for default -->
        <namespace>/your_robot_namespace</namespace>
        <!-- The topic name where the position will be published -->
        <remapping>odom:=/odom</remapping>
    </ros>
    <!-- Replace with your robot's main link -->
    <body_name>base_link</body_name>
    <!-- Update rate in Hz -->
    <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
    <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
    <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin>

Now after including the plugin, save the file and compile and source your workspace. In my case, it was:

Now you have successfully published a plugin with your gazebo that will return the real-time values of the position and orientation etc.
To check it
On the terminal open
ros2 node list
And that would give you all the nodes that are running on your gazebo. Look for /odom.
Another important thing is that your gazebo must be open with your robot in the gazebo for it to work.
If still it doesn't work then, open the terminal and type

ros2 run teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard

and that would open a keyboard to operate your robot and now after typing

ros2 node list

You'll get your required result

/odom

Now to check the live values that your odom is returning. Use this command

ros2 topic echo /odom

This will give all the live values of position; angular and linear velocities and orientation etc.
Now the next step is to plot these values.
For that you need

rqt_plot

If you haven't installed rqt_plot, you first have to do that. In my case

sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get install ros-foxy-rqt-plot

and then run the command to open rqt-plot

ros2 run rqt_plot rqt_plot

this will open an rqt_plot on your screen

A plot of this kind would be opened on your screen. Now the last step in the process is to include the topics and then include them in your plot. For position of x, in my case

/odom/pose/pose/position/x

and that you have to write in the topic portion of your matplot interface.

This opens up, which shows that you have successfully put the x-axis position to plot now repeat it for y and z by

/odom/pose/pose/position/y


/odom/pose/pose/position/z

For Linear Velocities:

/odom/twist/twist/linear/x


/odom/twist/twist/linear/y


/odom/twist/twist/linear/z

For Angular Velocities:

/odom/twist/twist/angular/x


/odom/twist/twist/angular/y


/odom/twist/twist/angular/z

Now move your robot in gazebo with the help of the keyboard and see the positions being plotted on the graph.
I hope that clears all the confusions, in case of any queries feel free to ask.
